# Why does theano.tensor.stack() make function compilation time so much faster?

Tags: python, theano

I'm writing a function which takes in an array of enzyme and substrate concentrations, and returns an array of maximum reaction rates.

```
import theano.tensor as T
from theano import function

self.rateFunction = function(enzyme_vars_array + substrate_vars_array, rateExpressionsArray, on_unused_input='ignore')
```

enzyme_vars_array and substrate_vars array are lists of theanor tensors, built using T.dscalar('name_of_thing').

rateExpressionsArray is a list of python expressions which gives the kinetic rate of a reaction in terms of the theano tensors in 
enzyme_vars_array and substrate_vars array. Because some enzyme and substrate concentrations may not be used, I've included the on_unused_input='ignore' flag.

The size of these inputs are:

len(enzyme_vars_array) = 132

len(substrate_vars array) = 17

len(rateExpressionsArray) = 2402

Running this line of code as written causes an extremely long compilation, at least 5 minutes (I gave up waiting eventually).

However this single change reduced the compilation time to only a few seconds:

```
self.rateFunction = function(enzyme_vars_array + substrate_vars_array, T.stack(rateExpressionsArray), on_unused_input='ignore')
```

What is theano.tensor.stack() doing which causes this massive change in compilation time? And what about the original formulation made it so slow?

**Edit:**

While writing up example code which can be run, this problem got stranger. This code generates examples of enzyme_vars_array, substrate_vars_array, and rateExpressionArray:

```
import theano.tensor as T
from theano import function
import numpy as np


enzyme_names = ['e1','e2','e3','e4','e5','e6','e7','e8','e9','e10','e11','e12','e13','e14','e15','e16','e17','e18','e19','e20', '21','e22','e23','e24','e25','e26','e27','e28','e29','e30','e31','e32','e33','e34','e35','e36','e37','e38','e39','e40','e41','e42','e43','e44','e45','e46','e47','e48','e49','e50','e61','e62','e63','e64','e65','e66','e67','e68','e69','e70','e71','e72','e73','e74','e75','e76','e77','e78','e79','e80','e81','e82','e83','e84','e85','e86','e87','e88','e89','e90','e91','e92','e93','e94','e95','e96','e97','e98','e99','e100','e101','e102','e103','e104','e105','e106','e107','e108','e109','e110','e111','e112','e113','e114','e115','e116','e117','e118','e119','e120','e121','e122','e123','e124','e125','e126','e127','e128','e129','e130','e131','e132']

substrate_names = ['s1','s2','s3','s4','s5','s6','s7','s8','s9','s10','s11','s12','s13','s14','s15','s16','s17']

enzyme_vars_array = T.dscalars(*enzyme_names)

substrate_vars_array = T.dscalars(*substrate_names)


rateExpressionsArray = [0]*2292

# Populate rateExpressionsArray with random expressions in terms of the theano variables
for index, rateExpression in enumerate(rateExpressionsArray):
    random_enzyme_index = np.random.randint(len(enzyme_vars_array))
    random_substrate_index = np.random.randint(len(substrate_vars_array))

    rateExpressionsArray[index] = enzyme_vars_array[random_enzyme_index] * substrate_vars_array[random_substrate_index]


rateFunction = function(enzyme_vars_array + substrate_vars_array, rateExpressionsArray, on_unused_input='ignore')
```

This is the code I expected to run slowly (as it runs without T.stack). However in this example it now runs at a perfectly reasonable pace. When I replace the last line with this however:

```
rateFunction = function(enzyme_vars_array + substrate_vars_array, T.stack(rateExpressionsArray), on_unused_input='ignore')
```

It runs extremely slowly again, the opposite of my observed behavior in my actual code!

I considered possible differences between this example and my actual code and realized that my real rateExpressionsArray is very sparse, it mostly consists of a placeholder which just returns a default value, with only a few real expressions. So rewriting my example code to look more like this, I have:

```
import theano.tensor as T
from theano import function
import numpy as np


enzyme_names = ['e1','e2','e3','e4','e5','e6','e7','e8','e9','e10','e11','e12','e13','e14','e15','e16','e17','e18','e19','e20', '21','e22','e23','e24','e25','e26','e27','e28','e29','e30','e31','e32','e33','e34','e35','e36','e37','e38','e39','e40','e41','e42','e43','e44','e45','e46','e47','e48','e49','e50','e61','e62','e63','e64','e65','e66','e67','e68','e69','e70','e71','e72','e73','e74','e75','e76','e77','e78','e79','e80','e81','e82','e83','e84','e85','e86','e87','e88','e89','e90','e91','e92','e93','e94','e95','e96','e97','e98','e99','e100','e101','e102','e103','e104','e105','e106','e107','e108','e109','e110','e111','e112','e113','e114','e115','e116','e117','e118','e119','e120','e121','e122','e123','e124','e125','e126','e127','e128','e129','e130','e131','e132']

substrate_names = ['s1','s2','s3','s4','s5','s6','s7','s8','s9','s10','s11','s12','s13','s14','s15','s16','s17']

enzyme_vars_array = T.dscalars(*enzyme_names)

substrate_vars_array = T.dscalars(*substrate_names)


# This is the placeholder expression which returns an input unmodified
noRate = T.dscalar('noRate')
rateExpressionsArray = [noRate]*2292

# Include only a handful of nontrivial expressions
for index in xrange(1,50):
    random_enzyme_index = np.random.randint(len(enzyme_vars_array))
    random_substrate_index = np.random.randint(len(substrate_vars_array))
    rateExpressionsArray[index] = enzyme_vars_array[random_enzyme_index] * substrate_vars_array[random_substrate_index]


rateFunction = function(enzyme_vars_array + substrate_vars_array + [noRate], T.stack(rateExpressionsArray), on_unused_input='ignore')
```

This produces the original behavior - when only a few indexes in rateExpressionArray are nontrivial expressions, the code runs fast with T.stack() and slowly without T.stack(). To replicate the slow version, replace the last line with:

```
rateFunction = function(enzyme_vars_array + substrate_vars_array + [noRate], rateExpressionsArray, on_unused_input='ignore')
```

So it seems that T.stack produces different behavior on sparse versus dense inputs? I'm even more confused as to the function and mechanism of stack() now. Any insights into what's happening here would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Can you share more of your code? Or, perhaps better, can you find a simpler example that can be copied, pasted, and run with no dependencies, that demonstrates the behaviour?